# How do I build a C# file through Mono on Linux command line?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I wrote a simple Hello World program in C# using Visual Studio 2013. I tried to compile it on the command line in Linux using:

```
mono --aot test.cs
```

However when I do that, I get the error:

```
Cannot open assembly 'test.cs': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

The file is just a typical C# console application using the default template that Visual Studio gives you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `gmcs` in order to compile your code, and `mono` to execute the interpreter, as one use `javac` and `java` commands.

You may reread the [mono basics:](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics)

Let's say you have a C# file with the following code:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }

}
```

**Compiling within the shell:**

```
gmcs hello.cs
```

**Executing it from the shell:**

```
mono hello.exe
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! This is my first time using mono so I've got a bit of learning to do. Thanks!

Comment: Google is your friend. [baidu if your are from China]

Comment: Lol I prefer to use Bing actually